# How to get the pressure force applied on an object?

Tags: node-editor

Here is my problem, I am trying to access the force applied by the wind on a cube in the node panel.

Does anyone know what the name of the node is ?

Comment: Is this animation nodes?

Comment: Yes, of course. Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

A force field object can not be edited using nodes.
Nodes are reserved for materials.

I am guessing you want to animate the force within to simulate increasing wind force. You can do this by selecting your wind force and opening up the physics tab.

[image]

In this tab hover the strenght attribute and press 'i' to insert a keyframe.
Than place another keyframe somewhere else on your timeline to animate the wind force. Same can be done for the other attributes.

Comment: Actually, I want to access the force the wind is applying on a specific objet, in order to later color the object consequently to the value of this force. I am looking for a node that gives me the value of the force applied by the wind on the object

Comment: I don't see a way of changing a material based on the strenght value of the force-field. You can however create a seperate animation for the color of the object in question to gradually change it as the force field increases. The animations will be managed seperate from eachother but if done right you shouldn't notice the difference. Then again, I do not know the exact situation you are working with.